# my fire simulation is not reflecting the right way

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fire

so i'm trying to make a fire simulation reflect off my desk but im having a problem. it looks like there's a box there but the only things that are being rendered are the smoke simulation, the plane that its reflecting off of, and the cylinder. i'm using the wisp shader for the fire if that means anything.

[image: fire without the cylinder]

[image: fire with cylinder]

Comment: please provide the .blend file. See here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5567" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5567/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from how you mix the things together. In your second layer, the volume domain is excluded, so it's not rendered.

A way to go arround this is to render everything from one layer, but instead of mixing two layers, we will mix different passes of one layer according to object IDs, thanks to the [ID Mask node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/id_mask.html#bpy-types-compositornodeidmask).

Here's my version:

[image]

I'm sure it's not the best solution, but it's all I can think of.